# How to make animation move slower on progress bar

Tags: objective-c, uiprogressview, uiprogressbar

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10000 animations:^{
    [self.RecomendedBar setProgress:self.whatProgressbarShouldBe animated:NO];
}];
```

It's pretty obvious that I set progress within an animation block whose time I set at 10k

Yet it's still so fast. Less than 1 seconds.

In fact, if I do this:

```
    [self.RecomendedBar setProgress:self.whatProgressbarShouldBe animated:NO];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:10000 animations:^{

    }];
```

It is still animated with less than 1 seconds even thought the progressview bar is outside animation block.

Comment: The `progress` property is not animatable.

Comment: UIProgressView does a great job of reflecting the changes in variables as they update over time, things like large network operations or long-running calculations. UIProgressView is not a clock, however, and it will not do a good job of tracking variables that aren't actually changing. 

If you absolutely need to force UIProgressView to measure nothing but time, David's solution is certainly reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way to do this would be to use an NSTimer to generate time intervals used to update the progress bar. for example, to make a 15 second long progress bar:

```
 NSTimer *progressTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25f target:self selector:@selector(updateProgressBar) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

 - (void)updateProgressBar {
     float newProgress = [self.progressBar progress] + 0.01666; // 1/60
     [self.progressBar setProgress:newProgress animated:YES];
 }
```

declare the updateProgressBar method in your header. the increment is 0.016666... or 1/60, because a 0.25 second timer interval will occur 60 times in 15 seconds.